# How to properly manage an activity inside a compose project

Tags: android-activity, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a client project that is completely done jetpack compose. However one of the screens in an activity

```
 fun dataCaptureViewCompose(
    context: Context,
    viewLifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,
    dataCaptureView: DataCaptureView
): ComposeView = ComposeView(context).apply {
    setViewCompositionStrategy(
        ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnLifecycleDestroyed(viewLifecycleOwner)
    )

    setContent {
        DataCaptureViewCompose(dataCaptureView = dataCaptureView)
    }
}

@Composable
fun QRScreen(){
    val activity = LocalContext.current as Activity
            val intent = Intent(activity, BarcodeScanActivity::class.java)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
            activity.startActivity(intent)
}

@Composable
private fun DataCaptureViewCompose(dataCaptureView: View) {
    AndroidView(factory = { dataCaptureView })
}
```

This is One of the three classes that was given to me from the Barcode SDK to be used for compose. The Second one is a Camera Permission Activity class that inherits from AppCompatActivity() and is used to request camera permissions. The Third is a Barcode Activity Class that inherits the Camera Activity Class and BarcodeCaptureListener Class that comes with the SDK library. Barcode Class is where the onCreate is found and a bunch of other functions are found. The dataCaptureViewCompose is called in a function in Barcode Class and then that function is called in the onCreate. Navigating to QRScreen works fine, the activity is started and I am able to scan QR codes. Here is my problem, I need to make certain api calls that require the QR code and also make some navigation based on the result of the api call. Currently I have no way of making the calls directly from the composable because I dont have access to the Barcode Activity Class, I am also using dagger hilt. I want to handle everything in the composable so that i can inject the viewmodel. How can I get the result from barcode and pass it to the composable. This is the first time I ever had to incorporate an activity for a compose project.